# How to improve a MapActivity/MapView

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm looking for some ways to improve a MapActivity with additional features.

For instance, on several applications, I have seen animated popups when the user clicks on an item. This is the kind of things I would like to do (so that I get rid of the ugly alertDialog).

Maybe some libraries already exists? Or could you point me out some tutorials to do that on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get those popups (I'm assuming you mean an expanded ballon over that point) you can use this excellent library called [MapviewBalloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/). It's pretty easy to integrate this into your existing code. In order to modify it you can just modify the layout of the balloon and change it to something you'd like.

Here's an example image: [image]